# Different IDs for bulk NFT mint in ERC-1155

Tags: dapps, nft, erc-721, erc-1155

I would like to mint bulk `NFTs`, say 1000. `ERC-721` will be costly, therefore, I would like to use `ERC-1155` instead.

What I want to learn is, is it possible to have different IDs for each NFT? If so, how?

Edit 1:

We are building a game where players have NFT tools to mine some resources. Consider Axe to chop some wood.

A gamer can equip 3 Axes. These Axes don't differ in terms of productivty, they all produce same amount of wood. However, players can sometimes attach boosters on the NFTs. Therefore, I need to know on which Axe the booster is attached so that I can increase the production ratio of that particular NFT. We were considering to use mint IDs to differentiate the NFTs, however, I guess there are no mint IDs of the NFTs under a collection if we use ERC-1155, is that correct?

What I need to learn is:

1. If the Axe collection has 1000 Axe NFTs, does it all have unique IDs or does the collection itself gets an ID? I need to get Axe, say #250, is it possible?
2. If this is not possible by default, is there a workaround?
3. Will there be a mint cost difference between 721 and 1155?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each token in your ERC-1155 collection will have a unique ID.
Could you elaborate more on the problem you're facing?

Unless you're talking about nesting fungible or semi-fungible tokens as a 2nd-level structure?

For example you can have ERC-1155 collection with IDs = 1, 2, 3 and then under each ID you can have 100 fractions which are fungible tokens belonging each to their own ID.

Those fungible tokens won't have unique NFT IDs, but you can assign / transfer them to different Ethereum addresses and your collection contract will reflect how many of those "fractions" of each NFT does each address own.

Hope this helps, if not please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to create a collection. There will be thousands of NFTs under this collection, and I want these NFTs to have unique IDs. Is it possible or will there be single ID for the collection only?

Comment: edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: Yes, your NFTs in your ERC-1155 will have unique IDs. You can also have some resources / subtokens under each NFT if you go ahead with ERC-1155. Otherwise you can manage those via your backend as you mention and have it as a simple ERC-721 collection.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk minting ERC-721 is not costly. Although the implementation you are considering might be suboptimal.

In fact, the very first ERC-721 NFT, Su Squares, minted 10,000 tokens [in one transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x07bb215de77674c272b3a0e3f336642879f926df52e79d9ff8b26fdcbc4acb1b). The Su Squares smart contract is now open source, permissively licensed and is referenced in the ERC-721 document.

Comment: Do you suggest that we should go with 721 instead 1155? We're creating an NFT game where there only 16 different NFT cards but each card has several thousand of themselves.

Comment: Are the individual cards numbers (i.e. #1 of 3000, #2 of 3000, ...)? If yes, standard advice is use 721. If they are not numbered then use 1155.

Comment: There are tools to mine some resources. Consider Axe to chop some wood. A gamer can equip 3 Axes. The Axes don't differ in terms of productivty, they all produce same amount of wood. However, players can attach boosters on the NFTs. Therefore, I need to know on which Axe the booster is attached. If the NFTs under a collection don't have unique IDs, I guess I have to solve this problem in the backend.

Comment: If somebody sells their axe NFT using a third party marketplace then do you want that marketplace to know it is equipped with a certain wooden handle NFT? If yes, then they are serial-numbered assets.